# Chakra-UI navbar is not going full screen in React? Its stuck at the left side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I am trying to get this the navbar look like this:
[image]

But I am instead getting this:
[image]

How do I make it full screen?
My code look like this for now:

```
import {Grid, GridItem} from "@chakra-ui/react";

function App() {
    return (
    <Grid templateAreas={{
        base: `"nav" "main"`,
        lg: `"nav nav" "aside main"`
    }}>
        <GridItem area='nav' bg='coral'>Nav</GridItem>
        <GridItem area='aside' bg='gold'>Aside</GridItem>
        <GridItem area='main' bg='dodgerblue'>Nav</GridItem>
    </Grid>
    )}

export default App
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `width` prop with `full` or `100vw` value of your `Grid` component.